# What does "movie/film" actually mean?

Tags: cinema

I'm a native Vietnamese speaker. In Vietnamese we used the word "phim" (which is taken from French or English "film") to refer to just about any type of recorded cinematic video. I've tried to look in Cambridge and Oxford dictionaries but haven't got the satisfying definition. For example, [movie](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/american-english/movie):

> "a series of moving pictures, often telling a story, usually shown in a theater or on television; film" (Cambridge Dict.)

So my question is: What does "movie/film" actually mean? Can shows like Charmed, CSI, The Walking Dead or Game of Thrones *ever ever* be referred to as "movies/films"? Can "movie/film" ever ever be a cover term for everything that is filmed and released in theaters or on TV, such as drama TV shows, documentaries, etc.?

Comment: Are you asking about the distinction between "*a movie*" and "*a film*", or the distinction between movies and films and other forms of video media? To answer one of your questions: no, TV shows like "Charmed" are never referred to as "movies" or "films" by native speakers.

Comment: No. I'm asking a comprehensive yet simple definition of those synonymous terms. I listed the names of some TV shows, so my point is basically about the difference between "movie" and "TV series", and if "movie" can be cover term for cinematic videos in general.

Comment: *Movie* and *film* are both legacy terms today, vestiges of the past with various meanings depending on context and usage. 1. For the contemporary meaning and usage of these two terms, please see a more specialized glossary rather than a general English dictionary.  2. As for whether the Vietnamese word *phim* translates to English *movie* or *film*, yes, both words do have that meaning in contemporary usage. See also: http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Movie http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Film

Comment: I'm puzzled. You want a single umbrella term for movies and TV shows, in the way that "footwear" can cover hiking boots, sandals and stilettos? I don't think there is one. English is like that: an amazing number of words for styles of walking, but some thumping great holes.

Comment: @DavidPugh - probably *motion pictures* .

Comment: Amazon has a section like that.  It is called "Movies & TV".

Comment: @Josh: But it would have to cover Lena Dunham's "Girls" as well as "Game of Thrones". Also, ghod help us, the Jerry Springer Show. Motion pictures? I don't think so.

Comment: @DavidPugh "*video media*".

Comment: @David: Words or phrases develop for things or activities we do or need or want to talk about, for whatever reason. This, to say the least, varies a lot from group to group, and from person to person. The result is a mostly unfilled matrix, with resources for speakers to fill slots with their own nonce terms as needed. Some of them stick, some of them don't. Words are not designed to stick around, any more than animals are designed to become fossils. It happens pretty much arbitrarily, and very, very rarely.

Comment: @Dan Bron: Or just 'video'.

Comment: Thank you for all of your comments. No, I don't "want" a single umbrella term or something. I do want to know if "movie/film" can be that umbrella term, and that's it. I have argued with a Vietnamese teacher of English (who is not so good at speaking English and is just an average Vietnamese like everyone else); he insisted that "movie/film" could be a cover term for any type of cinematic video (just as one can expect from a Vietnamese), and last time I checked, it didn't seem to be the case. I asked this question just to make sure I wasn't the idiot.

Comment: In British English *film* is used for cinema, [DVDs](https://www.google.it/search?q=DVDs&oq=DVDs&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=%22dvd+films%22) and [TV](https://www.google.it/search?q=DVDs&oq=DVDs&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=%22TV+films%22).

Comment: and [*films for TV*](https://www.google.it/search?q=DVDs&oq=DVDs&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=%22films+for+TV%22) and [*films made for TV*](https://www.google.it/search?q=DVDs&oq=DVDs&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=%22films+made+for+TV%22)

Comment: The word "movies" technically comes from "moving pictures". However, that's not what it *means* nowadays. Television certainly consists of moving pictures, but TV shows are *not* movies, and absolutely no native speaker would call them such. Language is not rigid. Common usage defines meaning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Motion pictures are a comparatively recent invention. Here's how these words evolved:

[Film](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=film&allowed_in_frame=0) meant a thin coat of something (still does)...

> extended by 1845 to the coating of chemical gel on photographic plates. By 1895 this also meant the coating plus the paper or celluloid. Hence "a motion picture" (1905); sense of "film-making as a craft or art" is from 1920.

[Movie](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=movie&allowed_in_frame=0) is a shortened form of 'moving picture'.

By etymology, it looks like these terms are applicable to any video, but conventionally they are reserved for productions released theatrically.

Apart from that you have documentaries, direct-to-video features, TV shows (formally, series) and so on.

---

*Can "movie/film" ever ever be a cover term for everything that is filmed and released in theaters or on TV*?

**No, it can't.**

---

**EDIT:** Since people have shown interest in the comments, here are my thoughts on Made-for-TV and Direct-to-DVD features (We're digressing here, as this is not part of English language and usage):

I must say I *don't* consider them the same as movies.

To back this up, I present a short summary of relevant criteria a production must meet to be called a movie according to [the Oscars](http://www.oscars.org/sites/default/files/87aa_rules.pdf):

> a. feature length (defined as over 40 minutes),
>
> b. publicly exhibited by specified film formats.
>
> c. for paid admission in a commercial motion picture theater in Los
>   Angeles County, *(for our purposes, let's call it any city)*
>
> d. for a qualifying run of at least seven consecutive days,
>
> e. advertised ... in a manner customary to industry practice, and
>
> f. within the Awards year deadlines specified in Rule Three. (*not
>   relevant here*)
>
> **Films that, in any version, receive their first public exhibition
>   or distribution in any manner other than as a theatrical motion
>   picture release will not be eligible for Academy Awards in any
>   category.**
>
> Nontheatrical public exhibition or distribution includes but is not
>   limited to:
>
> - Broadcast and cable television
> - PPV/VOD
> - DVD distribution
> - Internet transmission

These features may be equally great in quality, and eligible for some other prestigious awards, but they are not *movies* in the classical sense.

Comment: What about "made for TV" movies?

Comment: @jamesqf: They fall under `...and so on`.

Comment: I think a "[made for TV movie](https://www.google.ca/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=made%20for%20tv%20movies)" is a real thing to talk about, and "straight to DVD" releases can also be called movies.