# "Film" umbrella term?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage, synonyms

Is the word "film" considered an umbrella term for movies, tv-series etc. or is it only used when referring to movies?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. You will likely find the answer at *[What does "movie/film" actually mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/244328/what-does-movie-film-actually-mean)*; also of interest will be *[Hypernym for “movie” and “TV series”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/127196)*

Comment: @choster is this question a duplicate as the links you posted answer it?

Comment: @lbf In my opinion, yes, it duplicates the *movie/film* question and I voted as such; others of course should apply their own judgment.

Comment: usually movies. sometimes only "good movies"; a _film_; not just a mere _movie_.